# How to handle per-request context with net/http

Tags: go

The first half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26754076/13860) demonstrates a pattern for sharing some per-request context between two handler methods. Sort of.

I'm looking for a way to do basically this, but with more than two handlers.

Imagine I need to call three (or more) `http.HandlerFunc`s with the same per-request context:

- Auth()
- DoStuff()
- OutputHTML()

Without resorting to a global map (e.g. gorilla/mux), is there any way, using the standard `http.Handler` interface, to pass per-request context between these functions?

Comment: Note that the global mutex-protected map of gorilla/context has a pretty low performance hit: I benchmarked this last week and saw a < 2k req/s difference with a lot of concurrency (GOMAXPROCS=8) - 40k req/s vs. 42k req/s for non-global map (for an artificial situation where I was only hitting the map, making results worse). The other solution is to satisfy `http.Handler` with a `func(context.Context, http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)` type that threads a `net/context.Context` through the handlers that need it: https://joeshaw.org/net-context-and-http-handler/#custom-context-handler-types

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat and wrap the Request.Body (a ReaderCloser interface) with your context.

Here's an example: [webctx.go](https://github.com/dbudworth/webctx/blob/master/webctx.go)

when you want your context, just type assert request.Body to be your type.
Only trick is your type must hold the original body and implement the ReaderCloser methods... but that's a minimal amount of code.

Comment: That's clever. I suppose the reason to wrap Request.Body rather than Request, is because .Body is an interface, right?  Any reason not to wrap, say, ResponseWriter instead? (I'm just trying to understand the full implications of this design)

Comment: exactly, Request is a struct so you can't really wrap that.  As for Request.Body vs ResponseWriter... No reason other than I personally think of a context object as being part of processing a request.  And not so much about the response itself.  just a personal preference

Comment: Makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation.